# Post Redirect Get pattern and use in a RESTful resource-based service when supporting searching

Tags: http, rest, post

If I have a HTTP based RESTful service and I want to POST a search resource and use the PRG pattern for returning the URL to the search-result resource, I have to persist the search-result resource on the server.

Is this a good idea?

If I do persist the search-result resource how long is it persisted for?

Can I control this by a HTTP header of some kind?

Cheers

AWC

Comment: Why do you need to persist the query?

Comment: I'm not persisting the query, I'm persisting the results of the query which are returned as part 'G' of PRG pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think REST or HTTP can provide you with any guidance on this.  How long the search results should persist for is purely a function of how big they are, how expensive they are to calculate, how dynamic the data is, how often the same results are requested and how much money do you want to spend on hardware to get performance.

Having said that, you could use 410 Gone to interesting effect.  After a period of time you could throw away the results but keep the query parameters and saved resource url.  If you get a request to that URL after the results have been thrown away, you could return 410 Gone with the query parameters in the body.  The client could be prompted to decide if they want to re-issue the query.

Depending on the data, you could even hide the re-query from the client.  However, depending on the type of data being returned that could be misleading to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You'll notice that when you do a google search, the page with the results actually has your search in the url, and if you inspect the form on google's home page that the form is actually set to GET. So in a search scenario it is actually common to just use a single get request and not a post request, since you are using it to "GET" search results based on a particular query.

A "POST" event might be more useful when you are "POST"ing data, like when you post something on a message board. You are adding data to a database, message board, user profile, etc.

If getting the search result is a heavy tax on your system, then you might want to look into a way of caching the results based on the search term, so that whenever a get request is made for that term, the results are easier to pull together.

Comment: Just to point out that sometimes the POST might get big, in that case the GET will have problems, assume you want to search for a picture, therefore the base64 can be big, and it will pass the 2083 characters max of the URL (at least in IE). There are some valid reasons for using a POST to do a "Query", in my case I have a big form with a bunch of criteria, some texts, that make a pain the GET approach.